# edit docx file using phpword

Tags: php, phpword

is it possible to edit existing docx file using phpword?

i want to add footer text to my existing docx file.

there are lot of examples but those examples are creating the doc file from scratch not editing the file
can someone link to me an example? thank you

just like this.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
// New portrait section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
// Add header
$header = $section->createHeader();
$table = $header->addTable();
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(4500)->addText('This is the header.');
$table->addCell(4500)->addImage('_earth.jpg', array('width'=>50, 'height'=>50, 'align'=>'right'));
// Add footer
$footer = $section->createFooter();
$footer->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGES}.', array('align'=>'center'));
// Write some text
$section->addTextBreak();
$section->addText('Some text...');
// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('HeaderFooter.docx');
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can edit.

From documentation

> [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) is a library written in pure PHP that provides a set of
>   classes to write to and read from different document file formats. The
>   current version of PHPWord supports Microsoft Office Open XML (OOXML
>   or OpenXML), OASIS Open Document Format for Office Applications
>   (OpenDocument or ODF), and Rich Text Format (RTF).

Actually this is the procedure

1. **Load our existing file as template.**
2. **Edit**
3. **Save**

From the Documentation, I found an example,

```
<?php
include_once 'Sample_Header.php';
// Template processor instance creation
echo date('H:i:s'), ' Creating new TemplateProcessor instance...', EOL;
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('resources/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx');
// Variables on different parts of document
$templateProcessor->setValue('weekday', htmlspecialchars(date('l'))); // On section/content
$templateProcessor->setValue('time', htmlspecialchars(date('H:i'))); // On footer
$templateProcessor->setValue('serverName', htmlspecialchars(realpath(__DIR__))); // On header
// Simple table
$templateProcessor->cloneRow('rowValue', 10);
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#1', htmlspecialchars('Sun'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#2', htmlspecialchars('Mercury'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#3', htmlspecialchars('Venus'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#4', htmlspecialchars('Earth'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#5', htmlspecialchars('Mars'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#6', htmlspecialchars('Jupiter'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#7', htmlspecialchars('Saturn'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#8', htmlspecialchars('Uranus'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#9', htmlspecialchars('Neptun'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowValue#10', htmlspecialchars('Pluto'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#1', htmlspecialchars('1'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#2', htmlspecialchars('2'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#3', htmlspecialchars('3'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#4', htmlspecialchars('4'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#5', htmlspecialchars('5'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#6', htmlspecialchars('6'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#7', htmlspecialchars('7'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#8', htmlspecialchars('8'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#9', htmlspecialchars('9'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('rowNumber#10', htmlspecialchars('10'));
// Table with a spanned cell
$templateProcessor->cloneRow('userId', 3);
$templateProcessor->setValue('userId#1', htmlspecialchars('1'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userFirstName#1', htmlspecialchars('James'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userName#1', htmlspecialchars('Taylor'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userPhone#1', htmlspecialchars('+1 428 889 773'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userId#2', htmlspecialchars('2'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userFirstName#2', htmlspecialchars('Robert'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userName#2', htmlspecialchars('Bell'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userPhone#2', htmlspecialchars('+1 428 889 774'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userId#3', htmlspecialchars('3'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userFirstName#3', htmlspecialchars('Michael'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userName#3', htmlspecialchars('Ray'));
$templateProcessor->setValue('userPhone#3', htmlspecialchars('+1 428 889 775'));
echo date('H:i:s'), ' Saving the result document...', EOL;
$templateProcessor->saveAs('results/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx');
echo getEndingNotes(array('Word2007' => 'docx'));
if (!CLI) {
    include_once 'Sample_Footer.php';
}
```

Now see the lines of code given below , how to access existing header and footer

```
$headers = $section->getHeaders();
$header1 = $headers[1]; // note that the first index is 1 here (not 0)

$elements = $header1->getElements();
$element1 = $elements[0]; // and first index is 0 here normally

// for example manipulating simple text information ($element1 is instance of Text object)
$element1->setText("adding text here - old part: " . $element1->getText());

$footers = $section->getFooters(); // to access footer
```

You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/master/samples) . If you want to add more styles, please read this [page](https://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html). And you can also see some [recipes](https://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes.html) in their documentation.

Answer (score -1):

In the footer of your file(template) docx, you can put a variable like this ${var1}.

- Open a file as template with "TemplateProcessor".

  ```
  $templateObject = new TemplateProcessor($filename);
  ```
- Replace var1 variable in your file

  ```
  $templateObject->setValue('var1', 'test');
  ```
- Transform your template into a PhpWord

  ```
  $fileName = $templateObject->save();
  $phpWordObject = IOFactory::load($fileName);
  unlink($fileName);
  return $phpWordObject;
  ```
- Save/Render your phpWord instance

  ```
  // create the writer
  $writer = $this->wordService->createWriter($phpWordObject, 'Word2007');
  // create the response
  $response = $this->wordService->createStreamedResponse($writer);
  // adding headers
  $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
      ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
      'export.docx'
  );
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/msword');
  $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
  $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
  $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Might be useful for Laravel 5 users. You can use this in your controllers.

```
public function wordDocumentFromWordTemplate() {

    $templateFile = public_path('templates') . '/template-file.docx';
    $templateObject = new TemplateProcessor($templateFile);

    $templateObject->setValue('var1', 'Text for var1');

    $wordDocumentFile = $templateObject->save();

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/msword',
        'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0'
    ];

    return response()->download($wordDocumentFile, 'result.docx', $headers);
}
```